# Using superkaramba widgets in Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, kde, widgets, plasma-5

Is there a way to use superkaramba widget in Kubuntu 15.04? Some web pages say that it should be possible but I could not find out how.

Since no package "superkaramba" was available I installed "plasma-scriptengine-superkaramba" which is the replacement according to apt-get.

However I could not find a way to actually install a karamba widget. The repository only lists plasmoids and when trying to install it from local file, the dialog does not allow to select *.skz files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is easy. SuperKramba does not integrate into the Plasmoid interface. Installing script engine creates a new entry in the application launcher "SuperKaramba" that can be used to handle SuperKaramba widgets.